# How do I correct incorrect output from diff on Unix

Tags: command-line

I have 2 similar files that I'm comparing.  There is only 1 incorrect value on the first line but I get output in this pattern

```
1c1
contents of 4th line
\ No newline at end of file
```

The contents of the 4th line are exactly the same.  I know because I duplicate both files and only changed the first line.

```
/usr/bin/diff -s 'file1' 'file2' | :
```

I'd prefer not to see the similar lines and see the actual difference.  Something like:

1c1    San Jose        ->>>    San JoseX

I have tried these parameters --side-by-side --suppress-common-lines and I always lines that match.

I'm using the | : to suppress the error from diff.

Data for the files just remove the x at the end of San Jose

```
CA  San Josex   3   5
    Sunnyvale       2.5
NY  New York    7.25    7
    Platburg        8
```

Comment: There pretty much has to be something weird about the files to cause this, and without more info about the files I don't think anyone'll be able to guess what's going on. Can you create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of files that show the problem -- basically, remove unnecessary parts (like everything after line 5, maybe replace lines 2-5 with just the digits 2-5, etc) until you have a pair of files that're just bare minimum to show the problem, and then edit those into the question?

Comment: How do I upload the files then.  They are already pretty simple.

Comment: If tried to use the picture feature to upload them but that won't work even if you rename the extension.  If you give me a email address I'll send them.  Adding the raw text to the original message really won't expose a problem if there is one with the file.  I originally duplicate these files and ONLY changed the first line in the file.

Comment: There may be something weird about the way the files are formatted. What does `file file1` print (the `file` command will attempt to infer a file's format). What about `LC_ALL=C cat -vet file1` (which will print the file with normally-invisible characters represented by visible sequences)?

Comment: Which editor are you using? Can you make whitespace visible in your editor? I suspect the last line has a newline in one version, and no newline in the other. In any case, whitespace is often the reason why some files differ even if they appear to have the same content (e.g. tab vs. spaces, additional/missing whitespace).

Comment: If you have Xcode installed what does FileMerge.app show?